# Why are there different animations with setNavigationBarHidden?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In my viewDidAppear method I call

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

and the navigation bar is hidden by sliding it to the left. However, if I detect a tap gesture then do the following

```
if([self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden]){
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
} else {
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

the navigation bar is shown/hidden by sliding it up/down from the top of the screen. Am I doing something to cause the different types of animation or is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it depends on the state of the VC.

If a VC shows or hides the navigation bar in ViewWillAppear, the navcon animates the (dis)appearance of the bar in coincide with the appearance of the new VC.

Also see comments in:
[changing the direction that the hide animation moves a navigationBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076809/self-navigationcontroller-setnavigationbarhiddenyes-animatedyes-direction)